# How to make Section collabsible?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have my `SectionedFetchResults` sorted in a `List` exactly following [the Intro](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10017/?time=1092) from WWDC this year.
It's stated, that the Sections should automatically be collapsible, and they are in the Preview:
[image: Preview]

However, my experience has been very different:
[image: Simulator]

even though I'm using the same Code:

```
var items: SectionedFetchResults<String, Item>

var body: some View {
    List{
        ForEach(items) { section in
            Section(header: Text(section.id)) {
                ForEach(section) { item in
                    Text(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }.onDelete { indexSet in
                        withAnimation {
                          deleteItem(
                            for: indexSet,
                            section: section,
                            viewContext: viewContext)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }.navigationTitle("Liste")
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a `NavigationView` in the hierarchy?

Comment: There is in the parent View, and I just added the snippet in there, there everything appears normally, is there a way to keep the List as destination of NavigationLink, or is the direct outer NavigationView a necessity? @Yrb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `SidebarListStyle` to your `List`.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Header")) {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                    Text("Item 3")
                    Text("Item 4")
                }
            }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle()) //<-- Here
        }
    }
}
```

Default `List` styles have changed by version and might (?) also be affected by parent views in the navigation hierarchy. Adding the `SidebarListStyle` explicitly seems to add the collapsible functionality reliably.

There is also a newer syntax for this:

```
.listStyle(.sidebar)
```